# What is an "optional HTTP response header"?

Tags: http, discord

The [discord API documentation for rate-limits](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits) says:

> For every API request made, we return optional HTTP response headers containing the rate limit encountered during your request.

What is an '*optional* HTTP response header' and how do I specify that I want them in my request? Current requests do not return this information.

The Headers I do get (C# .NET5):

```
Date: Sun, 14 Feb 2021 21:12:57 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d4b6460a960478da3551a5606b9f866291613337177; expires=Tue, 16-Mar-21 21:12:57 GMT; path=/; domain=.discord.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax; Secure
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 478
Via: 1.1 google
Alt-Svc: h3-27=":443"
Alt-Svc: h3-28=":443"
Alt-Svc: h3-29=":443"
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: 0843fcc477000040cbe70cf000000001
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=fxLWkQ1cyI0hkx7Y37u4aJgggXkYoLCR0xyug0Z2FR7ezTwHBST98EvVj3Now5wzxkLu4IJSsr%2F4FiRWaPtga0cg7iZNpLk9%2BjzAmQ%3D%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"max_age":604800,"report_to":"cf-nel"}
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: 6219ca4d8c1640cb-LHR
```

Comment: I think they're "optional" in the sense that the HTTP standard does not define them, not that Discord only includes the rate limit headers in some responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internet works by different machines using an agreed protocol for exchanging data. The protocol is defined by by IANA ratification of a description which, even after ratification, is described as a Request For Comments (rfc).  The RFC for HTTP version 1.1 is [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6). Although this has now been superceded, it provides a usual reference point and most of the information therein is still applicable. You'll see [the same requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-1.2) in most RFCs:

> The key words "MUST", "MUST NOT", "REQUIRED", "SHALL", "SHALL NOT",
> "SHOULD", "SHOULD NOT", "RECOMMENDED", "MAY", and "OPTIONAL" in this
> document are to be interpreted as described in RFC 2119 [34].

There are certain things which are essential to the operation of the protocol, and things which are add additional value. Specifically in relation to discord, the headers it is talking about are not required for processing the request, but provide information about why future requests may fail.

As you have noted, the example you have provided here does not contain the headers described in the document you linked.

Discord [provide a facility](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) for you to ask them for support or to report issues. I suggest that should have been your first port of call.